# How would I write the Null and Alternative Hypothesis for this research question?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Suppose that you had subjects learn a series of sentences and then recall the subject noun from each sentence.You manipulate the type of imagery included in the sentence (FACTOR A), ordinary and bizarre imagery.You also manipulated the amount of complexity of the sentences (FACTOR B), low and high complexity.Each subject had 30 sentences to learn; thus a maximum of 30 nouns could be recalled. Since this design is 2by 2 factorial design, you have four experimental conditions. 20 subjects participated in each of the four
conditions.

1. Write out your null and alternative hypothesis for each of the statistics of interest, write in words and as a mathematical expression. (For example, for a b-coefficient in a categorical regression in words: a)H0: The mean of group 1 is not different than the mean of group 2 and b) as a mathematical expression:
   b1=0)

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.